# Change number of bar chart categories

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I found [this beautiful example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/bar-chart/):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title  = Contributions per category at LaTeX-Community.org,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    symbolic y coords = {LaTeX, Tools, Distributions, Editors},
    nodes near coords,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates { (57727,LaTeX) (5672,Tools) (2193,Distributions) (11106,Editors) };
  \addplot coordinates { (14320,LaTeX) (1615,Tools) (560,Distributions) (3075,Editors)  };
  \legend{Topics, Posts}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It gives a nice bar chart:

[image: nice bar chart]

But the example is **incredibly misleading!** See what happens when I try to remove the 'editors' category:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title  = Contributions per category at LaTeX-Community.org,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    symbolic y coords = {LaTeX, Tools, Distributions},
    nodes near coords,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates { (57727,LaTeX) (5672,Tools) (2193,Distributions) };
  \addplot coordinates { (14320,LaTeX) (1615,Tools) (560,Distributions) };
  \legend{Topics, Posts}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: oops]

Clearly something is missing and/or going wrong. How do I properly add or remove categories from this bar chart? Why did it work in the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the example was missing a `ytick = data` argument, which ensures that there are exactly as many labels as categories.